# Transition functions of $S^3$ as a principal bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

Consider he action of $U(1)$ on $S^3$ by $(z_1,z_2)\cdot e^{i\phi}\mapsto(z_1e^{i\phi},z_2e^{i\phi})$. This action is clearly free and proper. Therefore we can consider $S^3$ as a principal bundle with structure group $U(1)$ over $S^3/U(1)\cong S^3/S^1\cong\mathbb{C}P^1$.

I know that we have charts for $\mathbb{C}P^1$ given by $U_i=\{[z_1,z_2]|z_i\neq0\}$. How do I compute the transition function $\varphi_{U_1U_2}:U_1\cap U_2\rightarrow U(1)$?

Comment: Why are you writing $\Bbb RP^1$? You mean $S^2$ or $\Bbb CP^1$. So why don't you start by writing down the trivializations on the open sets $U_j$ and then the definition of the transition function?

Comment: You are correct this should have been $\mathbb C P^1$. Do we get trivialization by taking the preimage of $U_i$ in the map quoitent map from $S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb C P^1$ ? I will add the definition of transition functions to the body of the text.

Comment: Yes, but you have to give a diffeomorphism $\pi^{-1}(U_j) \to U_j\times S^1$ that is compatible with the $S^1$ action.

Comment: Why do we need the diffeomorphism to be compatible with the $S^1$ action?

Comment: So that the $G$-principal bundle structure carries over to the trivializations.